# PostgreSQL: Finding students that have failed in more than 1 subject in their class (marks < 50)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a school table with 6 students each in class 1 and class 2, where each student has 5 subjects.

The table looks like this -

```
student_id      Standard       subject_id       marks
1               1              1                 30
2               1              1                 45
3               1              1                 45
4               1              1                 55
5               1              1                 80
6               1              1                 20
1               1              2                 40
2               1              2                 75
3               1              2                 25
4               1              2                 40
```

Standard is the class of the student.

My question is I need to calculate the number of students that have failed in more than 1 subject in their class (marks < 50)

So far my failed attempt:

```
select count(*) from 
(select student_id, marks < 50 as fail_value from school
group by 1,2
having count(subject_id) > 1
) as alias
where fail_value = 'true'
```

For reference, the expected result for the above table should look like this:

```
count_student_id
      2
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: I am using Postgresql

Comment: quick response? Afraid of becoming included in the result?

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: @jarlh Forgive me but I'm fairly new to stack overflow and don't really have a lot of idea about how to use formatted text for tables.

Comment: It's easy. When editing, write the data in proper columns, highlight and click `{}`.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: @jarlh got it. Thanks for the feedback. I edited the format of the table too.

Comment: Great, it looks much better now!

Comment: Don't forget that we need the expected result too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *derived table* (the subquery) will return each student_id having more than one marks < 50 class. Count the number of rows returned.

```
select count(*)
from 
(
  select student_id
  from school
  where marks < 50 
  group by student_id
  having count(subject_id) > 1
) as dt
```